# TFS Restore to another server

Tags: tfs, backup, azure-pipelines, devops, tfsbuild

I need a quick help, Request everyone to pls. pls. look on the same & let me know the response.

I want to restore & Configure the TFS on some other server as my original TFS server is not working.

So to restore the/ Configure the TFS on another server,I have the .bak file for the Tfs_Configuration.bak and Tfs_DefaultCollection.bak and one folder named as TFSData which is having the cache files. Screenshots are there. These 3 things are there.. So are these 3 sufficient to configure the tfs on some new server? Or anything else is needed?

Also pls. let me know where the TFS Data is actually saved in server? I am using git repository in TFS.

Pls. suggest

Comment: Have you tried the steps mentioned in below answer? Basically it should work for your.

Answer (score -1):

There is detailed guidance to move tfs into another server: [Move or clone from one hardware to another for Azure DevOps on-premises](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/move-clone-hardware?view=azure-devops).
The major steps:

1. Backup Reporting Service Databases, Reporting Service Encryption Key, TFS Databases (your Tfs_Configuration.bak and Tfs_DefaultCollection.bak)
2. Install new sql,tfs into new hardware
3. Restore items from step 1 into new hardware
4. Reconfigure server IDs and remap databases
5. Configure tfs app